# How do I access phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've installed phpMyAdmin but I don't seem to be able to access it.

I have tried browsing to both localhost/phpMyAdmin and 94.249.188.109/phpMyAdmin and it still says "Not Found".

How do I access phpMyAdmin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access phpmyadmin in lamp](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268167/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-in-lamp)

Answer (score 1):

Then you haven't installed it correctly; try installing with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

If that doesn't work, then try this fix:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Install phpmyadmin using

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql phpmyadmin
```

Then go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`. Just in case that does not work, go to `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/`.