# how to access phpmyadmin in lamp

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

I have installed `LAMP` on Ubuntu 12.10, and I want to access `PhpMyAdmin`, but I don't know it's URL.

I tried to access this URL : `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

But I got this problem :

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

And these are the instructions I followed to install lamp:

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you followed those installation instructions to the letter, phpmyadmin should at least be installed on your computer.  However, Apache configuration needs to be added for it to work.

When you installed phpmyadmin, it should have automatically set up its configuration for Apache, making it accessible at `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` (it's possible you may need the trailing slash?).

However, in case it didn't, you can re-run the initial configuration step with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
```

When changing Apache configuration, it should usually restart Apache automatically, but in case it doesn't, you can always restart Apache with:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

(Some changes require `restart` instead of `reload`).

Comment: Okey thanks for your help, I just re-run the initial configuration step and then it works, I have another question where can I find the www folder where I can put my php scritps ?

Comment: www folder is `/var/www` - you probably should normally ask follow-up questions as new questions because you'll get more people interested in answering them (they get rep) but this is probably too basic a question. Best of luck but you may have quite a learning curve ahead when it comes to things like security and Apache configuration.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to [@thomasrutter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268167/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-in-lamp/268182#268182) answer:

Just **in case someone doesn't know this** (i didn't for sometime), after running this command to reconfigure phpmyadmin

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
```

this screen will appear in your terminal, make sure the `*` is there inside the brackets `[]` like this `[*]` for `apache` using the <kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you are sure that you do have `lamp-stack` just open up your terminal and type:

```
edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and paste the following at the end of file:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then make sure you restart the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

After installing phpMyAdmin you need to configure it. There is great documentation here: [phpMyAdmin @ Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/phpMyAdmin)

Try it out.

Comment: The documentation he linked to will install phpmyadmin at this line: `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad. Nevertheless the link I provided gives more insight to the process of configuring phpMyAdmin

Comment: neon_overload's answer did not solve it on my machine, but the doc you linked to did. Had to include `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` in the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. I'm guessing this is a setup bug.