# How to remove symbolic link

Tags: symbolic-link

I was trying to create this symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

but I accidentally typed:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/php,yad,in /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

So now I want to correct it but it says symbolic link already exist.

Comment: sudo rm /usr/share/php,yad,in /var/www/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 240):

You can use `rm` to delete the symlink.

Example:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 2014-01-02 09:21 tmo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 2014-01-02 09:21 tmo2 -> tmo
```

Then ...

```
 rm tmo2
```

will remove the symlink.

Comment: permission denied. This is what i typed first: sudo ln -s /usr/share/php,yad,in /var/www/phpmyadmin

Comment: permission denied: You do know you need sudo if you want to use it in a situation you do not own the file? That goes for 'rm' too.

Comment: i did it rm /usr/bin/python and removed my python from ubuntu :S

Comment: @RaheelKhan no you did -not- You removed a SYMLINK. Python relies on this symlink though.  If you recreate that symlink python will be back.

Comment: I try this command but it seems that my file has been removed, I don't want to remove my file

Comment: @saeedmasoomi in the  example "rm tmo" removes the file. "rm tmo2" removes only the symlink. Make sure you remove the symlink (the one with the "l" at the front)

Comment: my output is like this `lrwxrwxrwx  1 saeed saeed    28 Dec 11 21:51 libGL.so -> /usr/lib/nvidia-173/libGL.so` and the second path doesn't exist so i stuck in this problem, thanks for your answer, what should be my command in this situation, if I use `sudo rm libGL.so then this file will be removed:(

Comment: If you get error: `rm: cannot remove dir/: Is a directory`,  remove the trailing `/`.

Comment: This is the only answer that works (Rinzwind)

Answer (score 46):

You can try the `unlink` command as well.

`unlink` is a similar command to `rm`. Therefore `rm <symlink>` will work same as `unlink <symlink>`

Here is the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unlink).

Comment: `unlink` has nothing to do with symlinks in particular.  See http://serverfault.com/a/38817/64085

Comment: While you are correct that `unlink` will remove the symlink, it is not an alias of `rm`. They are different, if ever so slightly. For one you cannot pass multiple arguments to `unlink`

Answer (score 17):

Suppose you were trying to do:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin/
```

but accidentally did:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/somethingelse /var/www/phpmyadmin/
```

To correct it simply navigate to the folder where the link is and *unlink*

```
cd /var/www/phpmyadmin/  
~:# unlink somethingelse
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following to remove the symbolic link

```
sudo rm /usr/share/php,yad,in
```

#### Explanation

- `rm` is the terminal command to remove a file. See `rm --help` for more options that it can take.
- `sudo` is used because the symbolic link was created with `sudo`. The file therefore belongs to root and your normal user will not have permission to edit/remove it (you would be able to force this if you had write permission on the directory, which would not be the case here).

#### Extra

Also see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/268167/164891) and my comment to the first answer to access phpmyadmin when getting a not found error after install.

Answer (score 3):

A small caveat I found was that I was trying to run `rm` and `unlink` on a symlink and I was getting an error that it was a directory.

```
$ rm folder_name/
rm: cannot remove ‘folder_name/’: Is a directory
$ unlink folder_name/
unlink: cannot unlink ‘folder_name/’: Not a directory
```

To remove the symlink, I used `unlink folder_name`. It was failing as there was a trailing `/` which causes the file to appear to be a directory.

Comment: Yeah, the key thing is trailing slash `/` at the end, which needs to be removed. Command `rm` works as well.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled here because I had to remove a `dpkg-divert` and the new package won't install until it was removed.

So if you have done something like this:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /usr/bin/gcc.real /usr/bin/gcc
```

You need to remove it with something like this:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove /usr/bin/gcc.real
```