# What is the right way to remove that symbolic link in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: symbolic-link

I've created this link:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

I've tried to remove it in these ways:

```
sudo unlink /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo rm ln /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo rm ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

These three ways didn't work for me. What have I missed?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/399369/380067) is the answer to the linked duplicate that fits your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `sudo rm /your/link/here`. It will remove the link.

Comment: @benos I pasted in the wrong path, I meant that both `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` and `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` are owned by root, so `sudo rm /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`.

Comment: Just want question for clarification please - The phpmyadmin in this path is just a symlink right? Deleting it will not make any problems? If it is only a symlink, why is there many information inside it?

Comment: @benos When you run `sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` you're creating a symbolic link in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` that points to `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`. By running `sudo rm /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` you just delete the symbolic link you just created.

Comment: WOW @kos you clarified much to me thank you! I was confused! I didn't fully understood that in symlinks we "Begin from the end" I.E intuitively it seems that it's apache.conf>>phpmyadmin.conf but it's actually being done from phpmyadmin.conf>>apache.conf (in this particular case).

Comment: @benos Yes, exactly. When in doubt check the `man` page: in this case `man ln` reports: `ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME`, i.e. first you mention the path to the target, then the path to the link. Most commands will follow this convention, unless you override it using specific options (for example both in `mv` and in `cp` you first specify one or more "target" folders / files, and then where to copy / move them, and as in `ln` you can change the order of the two with the `-t` option).