# cant access phpmyadmin after wordpress installation (LAMP stack)

Tags: server, apache2, directory, phpmyadmin, wordpress

initially i could able to log in phpmyadmin before i excecute the installtion of wordpress using http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin   .But after i had install wordpress environment ,i  have issue on wordpress and phpmyadmin

wordpress issue :

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );)
```

phpmyadmin :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin/index.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 8888)
```

Please help ,i m a newbie on linux

Answer (score 0):

They are 2 different sites. I will try to explain this as best as I can.
PhpMyAdmin is held in one location and when you loaded WordPress it writes it's own location. You need to go into the apache sites and create a new site to point to the the PhpMyAdmin directory.

I totally butchered that explanation. But I am pretty sure that is what happened.

It has been awhile since I worked with WordPress. So I am trying to remember all this. After closer look at my apache config. There is a conf file in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf with the directive `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin` .

This is supposed to allow any virt server dir "phpmyadmin" and direct it to the phpmyadmin directory. WordPress is probably overriding that directive.

I would create a new site in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ (note that you really should create it in available then link it) and then point it back to the default (/var/www/html/) and set it on a different port. And you should get it back.

Comment: [According to this post,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268167/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-in-lamp?rq=1) try this command
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin`

Comment: with that said ,if i am able to create a proper site and right points/directive for both of the application, i would able to proceed in installing the wordpress environment and meanwhile accessing phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 0):

[According to this guide](https://wpza.net/installing-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-with-wordpress-installed/), you just need to add the line:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html
```